# Java, While with multiple condition using or

Tags: java, while-loop

I have this while statement. which should exit when there is a whitespace or a `;` as a `char`. however it does not exit the loop when either of those conditions are true; 
when i use a `&&` it works better but now expects (obviously) both conditions to be true. which still does not help me.

```
    while ( !pt.get(locCursor).equals(';') || !pt.get(locCursor).equals(' ')){
        word = word + pt.get(locCursor);
        if (locCursor < pt.size()-1){
            locCursor ++;
        }else{
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your logic is off. The correct way is using logical AND, and it doesn't require "obviously" both conditions to be true. I.e. "while(not ';' and not ' ')".

Comment: how can it work "better"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at your condition. If result of `pt.get(locCursor)` is `;` then it is not space so second condition is `true` making entire condition true. If result is space then it is not `;` and again, entire condition is true.

Instead of

```
!egual(';') OR !equal(' ')
```

use

```
!( equal(';') OR equal(' ') )
```

or

```
!egual(';') AND !equal(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basiclly what you have is :

While (!x || !y) in OR ( || notation ) the truth table is as it follows

x y  r
0 0  0
1 0  1
0 1  1

1 1  1

Since you have invertion of the result ( ! infront both x and y ) your table is true only if you have both of them at 0.

Currently you are checking if the char is not equal to ';' or ' ' ( any char diff from one of those will break the while ).

I suppose you want to remove both of the '!' in the while.